# How to close all previous Android actvitities except the first one?

Tags: android, android-activity

Consider a hypothetical e-banking app which the following flow:

> HomeActivity -> CurrencyConverterActivity -> PickContactActivity -> InputDataTransferActivity ->
> TransferReviewActivity -> TransferConfirmationActivity

All activities (except HomeActivity) are invoked with the usual `startActivity()` and without `finish()`.
This is intentional, so user can review the inputs on previous screen. But once you reach TransferConfirmationActivity and press back, I want to go back to HomeActivity (and the other activities are killed).

How to do this?

Comment: Start all activities with startActivityForResult(). In TransferConfirmationActivity add a putExtra to the intent you use to finish() witch indicates that the receiving activity has to close too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag to achieve that.

According to [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) about `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the
> current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that
> activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and
> this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a
> new Intent.

```
val intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

start HomeActivity and add flag in intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, HomeActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Override `onBackPressed()` in `TransferConfirmationActivity` and return to `HomeActivity` like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TransferConfirmationActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

This will return the user to the existing instance of `HomeActivity`, while removing all the other activities from the stack.

If you would prefer to create a new instance of `HomeActivity` and return to that, just remove the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`.